# Limit the results of join on 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I have the query below, and it gets the correct data, but I need to limit the results of the join so that only the first row from the photos table is included. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT `listings`.*, `photos`.* 
FROM `listings` JOIN `photos` 
ON `photos`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` 
WHERE `listings`.`date_expires` >= '2016-08-10' AND `listings`.`visible` = '1'  AND `listings`.`spotlightListing` >= '2016-08-10'
```

How do I limit the above so I only get the first row from the photos table? Thanks!

Comment: First you need to define what is meant by "first row". Then [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5Deach+group) will probably be relevant.

Comment: What I meant by "first row" is when the tables are joined, the end result should be all of the matching "listings" results are returned, and each of those has the first result from the "photos" table. In other words, if each listing has 10 photos, and 5 listings match the WHERE, then I should only end up with 5 returned rows (each with only 1 photo as part of it).

Comment: There is no inherent order to the rows that end up joined; are you saying want an (effectively) random selection from the photos that match a listing, or expecting that the first photo entered for a listing will be the first joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `listings`.*, `photos`.* 
FROM `listings` 
JOIN `photos` ON `photos`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` 
WHERE `listings`.`date_expires` >= '2016-08-10' AND `listings`.`visible` = '1'
AND `listings`.`spotlightListing` >= '2016-08-10'
limit 1
```

I am sure you are talking about first photo of the list record.

Comment: Limit without order by is a fairly meaningless concept

Comment: I think in case of fetching only one photo we can go with order by but maybe we need to add LEFT join so if empty Result set then skip.

Comment: I tried that, but ran into the same problem as before - I only get 1 total result. I'm trying to get a result where all of the matching 'listings' table results are returned, and each of those results only has the first result of the joined 'photos' table.

Comment: OK add a clause group by listing_id